# Replacing array.filter(x => x.n === n)[0] with lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I do this very frequently:

```
var customer = people.filter(function(person) {
    return person.id === customerId;
})[0];
```

Semantically, I'm simplying saying "give me the unique element in the array that matches this predicate."

Now that I'm using lodash, what's the closest equivalent?

Comment: "the unique element" isn't really accurate. It's saying "the first of all the elements"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`findWhere`](https://lodash.com/docs#findWhere) function:

```
var customer = _.findWhere(people, { 'id': customerId });
```

Alternatively, you can use a combination of [`find`](https://lodash.com/docs#find) and [`matchesProperty`](https://lodash.com/docs#matchesProperty):

```
var customer = _.find(people, _.matchesProperty('id', customerId));
```

Generally, the `find(collection, predicate)` function finds you the first element in the `collection` that matches the `predicate`.

Answer (score 0):

The [find()](https://lodash.com/docs#find) function also accepts where-style object arguments directly. The [findWhere()](https://lodash.com/docs#findWhere) function is just calling `find()`.

```
var collection [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 } ];

_.find(collection, { id: 2 });
// → { id: 2 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.